# SHA-1 not getting displayed in android studio

Tags: android-studio, sha1

I am not able to see my SHA-1 key in the android studio.When clicking on the signing report sha-1 key is not displayed in console in Android Studio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After you run the signing report click Gradle Console its on the bottom right then just scroll until you see it

[image]